# When we have to use DBNull.Value, null and "" in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, types

I have a little confusion with the following things:

1. Null
2. DBNull.Value
3. ""

When I use Conditional Statements OR while assigning values, I am a little bit confused with these things. Sometimes it throws error and some times it works. I want to know when I want to use the above things. Are they specific with datatypes? I need your valuable suggestions please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`null` is one of two things:

- a reference that doesn't *actually* point to an object - just a "nothing" indicator (essentially, it is the value `0` as a reference)
- a `Nullable<T>` struct, which does not currently have a value (the `HasValue` property will also return `false`)

`DBNull` is specific to some parts of ADO.NET to represent `null` in the database. I have yet to think of a good reason why they didn't just use regular `null` here.

`""` is a string literal with length zero - a perfectly valid, but empty, string. The significance of this is that between `null` string and a `""` string, instance methods like `value.Trim()` will behave differently; `null.Trim()` will throw an exception; `"".Trim()` is just `""`. In general, using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` as a test makes this distinction go away.

Comment: +1: I don't have any first hand knowledge of why for DBNull, but I've found it useful personally in distinguishing between a null object in memory (which was bad for me) and a proper null value in the database (which I needed). I'm sure they could have built it to use null for both, but I found the distinction helpful.

Comment: @Joel fair enough; I've never had though, sadly. It is just one more thing to remember... `param.Value = value ?? DBNull.Value;` etc

Comment: @MarcGravell one case when it is useful, is in the return value of SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar. null is returned when the result set had zero rows. DBNull.Value is returned when there was at least one row, but the first column had a database NULL in it.

Comment: @MoeSisko yes, that is certainly one case where there is a difference, but that doesn't seem adequate justification for the amount of confusion this has added - frankly, just about any other API would have been preferable to having this null duality

Answer (score 12):

- `null` is internal to the language and simply means that the object reference currently doesn't refer to an actual object.  Basically, a key difference between value types (int, bool, etc.) and reference types (Object, any class, etc.) is that value types are a concrete value in memory and reference types are a pointer to a representation of the object in memory.  That pointer can sometimes point to, well, nothing.  In which case it's `null`.  It basically means "No C# object exists here."
- `DBNull.Value` is slightly different for the purpose of working with databases.  A database column can contain a `null` value.  However, when that data is selected into an object (such as a `DataTable`) in code, there *is* an object there to reference as far as the code is concerned.  However, that object contains a representation of a `null` value from the database.  Thus, `DBNull.Value` exists to represent that distinction.  It basically means "There is a C# object here which grabbed a value from a database, but that value is `null`."
- "" (or `string.Empty` if you want to use a built-in constant for that) is a valid value.  It exists, it's not `null`, it's in every way a `string`.  It just doesn't have any characters in it.  A useful tool for checking this is `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` which checks for either `null` or the empty string.

Comment: "so you don't have to instantiate a new string in memory to hold nothing" - the interning makes this pretty much moot. I wouldn't stress over the difference between `""` and `string.Empty`

Comment: @Marc Gravell: True, it's pretty well optimized at this point.  Old pet peeves die hard, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

null applies to C# null values.

System.DBNull.value applies to database specific NULL values.

When you use ExecuteScalar() it gives null if column not found or returned, but it column found and value is null there then it returns DBnull, means in a  column if value is null, if will return DBnull not null.